# Recursive method to add odd numbers

Tags: java, recursion, numbers, sum

I have the below snippet of code to use a recursive method to add the sum of odd numbers. 
I have already coded the iterative method successfully that adds the sum of all odd numbers between n and m which are entered by the user. I'd like to reach that goal but am started slow to make sure I understand what is happening. 
I know that it makes more sense to do it iteratively, however I am experimenting with the two types to see which is more efficient. I am stuck on the below as it is not doing what i want it to and i can't understand why.

```
import java.util.*;

public class SumofOdd
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
    int n = 0;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter an odd number");
    n = sc.nextInt();
    int x = add(n);
}

public static int add(int x)
{
    if (x == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return (x + add(x-1));
    }
}
}
```

I have changed the above to the below. It compiles however stops after I enter the number.
import java.util.*;

```
public class SumofOdd
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
    int n = 0;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter an odd number");
    n = sc.nextInt();

    if (n%2 == 0)
    {
        System.out.println("The number entered is even");
    }
    else
    {
        int x = add(n);
    }
}

public static int add(int x)
{
    if (x <= 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return (x + add(x-2));
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Note: You are currently not just using odd numbers but all numbers, since add(x) never checks if odd or even x. Calling add(x-1) with an already odd number will add an even number to your return value

Comment: Firts check if input number is odd one; second issue that `x + add(x-1)` is not correct, it should be `x + add(x-2) // 7, 5, 3,...` finally 'if (x == 0)' should be changed to `if (x <= 0)`

Comment: Could it just look like it stops because you are not printing the result?

Comment: This is not an answer, per se, but really a pointer to help you solve it yourself.  You say you have an iterative solution - a recursive solution would really be the same thing.  Try actually writing down in real words (i.e. not code) what your loop is doing.  "I begin with the start number I was given.  Each time through the loop, I (do something).  I stop looping when I get to end number I was given."

It's that "each time through the loop" that is the recursive part, and the "I stop looping" tells you the condition to stop your recursion on.

Answer (score 2):

```java
import java.util.*;
public class OddR{

    public static void main (String Args [])
    {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter an odd number");
        int max = s.nextInt();
        if((max% 2) == 0) {
            System.out.println(max + " is Even number and therefore is invalid");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Enter a greater odd number");
            int m = s.nextInt();
            if (m <max){
                System.out.println("Invalid data");

            }
            else{
                if((m % 2) == 0) {
                    System.out.println(m + " is Even number and therefore is invalid");

                }
                else{

                    int data =  (addodd(m)- addodd(max))+max;
                    System.out.print("sum:"+data);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static int addodd(int m)
    {

        if(m<=0)
        {
            return 0;    
        }

        if(m%2 != 0)
        {
            return (m+addodd(m-1));
        }
        else
        {
            return addodd(m-1);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the answer recursively of the sum of odd numbers from n to m

Answer (score 0):

```
public int addOdds(int n) {
  if (n <= 0) {
    return 0;
  }
  if (n % 2 == 0) {
    return addOdds(n - 1);  
  }
  return x + addOdds(n - 1);
}
```

Take care, I never tested the code.

Answer (score 0):

```java
class Oddsum {
    

   public int addodd(int n)
    {
     if(n<=0)
     {
       return 0;    
     }
     if(n%2 != 0)
     {
       return (n+addodd(n-1));
     }
     else
     {
       return addodd(n-1);
     }
   }
}

public class Xyz {

    public static void main (String[] v)
    {
      int n = 9;
      Oddsum o = new Oddsum();
      int data =  o.addodd(n);
      System.out.print("sum:"+data);
    }
}
```

This is working fine

Answer (score -1):

```
public static void main (String[] args){
        
       public static int oddSum(int s){
       if (s <= 0)
           return 0;
      
        else
            return s + oddSum(s -2);
       
         }
    }
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should also explain **what** the code does and **how** it helps. You can use the edit link below your answer to improve the post.

Comment: well done but why you did not just write if(s<=0) then return 0 !?

Comment: This code doesn't compile as you can't nest a method in another method like this in Java.